# Want to align this dynalic list items horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am doing drag and drop in angular and adding list items runtime in container box. These box are getting placed vertically. I want to add them horizontally with scroll bar to cover all items.

```
<div *ngFor="let dropzone of nestedList.dropzones;let i = index" class="col-md-6">
              <div class="dropzone box box-yellow">
                <!-- The dropzone also uses the list template -->

                <div [dndList]="{
          allowedTypes: ['container']}" [dndModel]="dropzone" [dndPlaceholder]="placeholder" class="col-md-12">
                  <div *ngFor="let item of dropzone">
                    <container *ngIf="item.type === 'container'" [list]="dropzone" [model]="item"></container>
                    <div *ngIf="item.type === 'Source'" [dndType]="item.type" [dndDraggable]
                      (dndMoved)="removeItem(item, dropzone)" [dndObject]="item" class="row">{{item.name}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: already tried `display: flex;`?

Answer (score 1):

if you use bootstrap you'r classes are wrong try this classe's each of items must be in col-* and all the item list wrapp inside the row in bootstrap

```
<div *ngFor="let dropzone of nestedList.dropzones;let i = index" class="row">
              <div class="dropzone box box-yellow">
                <!-- The dropzone also uses the list template -->
                 <div [dndList]="{
              allowedTypes: ['container']}" [dndModel]="dropzone" [dndPlaceholder]="placeholder" class="col-md-4">
                      <div *ngFor="let item of dropzone">
                        <container *ngIf="item.type === 'container'" [list]="dropzone" [model]="item"></container>
                        <div *ngIf="item.type === 'Source'" [dndType]="item.type" [dndDraggable]
                          (dndMoved)="removeItem(item, dropzone)" [dndObject]="item" class="row">{{item.name}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: this one is not workign. I tried this one.